# Transaction management using TransactionScope ()

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sql-server

I need to create a simple dotnet application which is going to call a stored procedure inside a loop (the stored procedure accepts few parameters and add them to a table). The requirement is that either all the rows get inserted or non.

To ensure this I've used:

```
using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope())
{
    foreach (EditedRule editedRules in request.EditedRules)
    {
            ...stored procedure call
    }
}
```

I've never used `TransactionScope` before, can someone please let me know if this code will work and will all my rows be rolled back.

I would also appreciate if there is a better approach to this.

Comment: wrap your code inside `try catch` blocks, so that you can implement rollback scenarios.And make sure to call `scope.Complete()`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming that your stored procedure does not create and commit its own transaction, this code will work, with one change: your code needs to code [`scope.Complete()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscope.complete(v=vs.110).aspx) before the end of the `using` block; otherwise, the transaction is going to roll back.

```
using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope()) {
    foreach (EditedRule editedRules in request.EditedRules) {
         ...stored procedure call
    }
    scope.Complete(); // <<== Add this line
}
```

The idea behind this construct is that the call of `Complete` will happen only if the block exits normally, i.e. there's no exception in processing the loop. If an exception is thrown, `scope` would detect it, and cause the transaction to roll back.

Comment: Also pay attention to isolation level https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173763.aspx

Answer (score 2):

The only thing I would call out about your code is to make sure to do a `scope.Complete()` in order to commit the transaction:

```
using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope())
{
   foreach (EditedRule editedRules in request.EditedRules)
   {
       // stored proc
   }

   scope.Complete();
}
```

if any exceptions occur during the using block, the transaction would be rolled back.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
using (var transaction = conn.BeginTransaction()) {
    try 
    {
       transaction.Commit();
    }  
    catch 
    {
        transaction.Rollback();
        throw;
    }
}
```